# Fetch only the body part from ajax response and add to the jsp

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

I have a jquery ajax call which is getting an html as a response and I want to display only the body part and append into the jsp body.

Any help is highly appreciated.

I have tried the below code but it not displaying the data.

```
$.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: true
        }).done(function(data, status){
     $('body').html(jQuery(data).find('body').html());
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, stat, error) {
            console.log(stat + ": " + error);
        });
```

Comment: What have you tried ? What is your code ?

Comment: You've provided a requirement, but not described the specific problem that you having achieving it.

Comment: Sorry, I have added what I have tried